# how to animate position in Order?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i want to move the Puzzle Tiles in sequence not at once

here my script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#left").click(function () {
            for (var i = 1; i < length; i++) {
                var string = "#s" + i.toString();
                $(string).animate({ "left": "+=50px" }, "slow");
            }


        });
```

with this code, all the Tiles move to the left at once but i want to move the tiles in Order

for example : move #s1 to left , after 2 second move #s2 to up and continue...

note that my moves is variable!

sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of the [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) method and the [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function like this:

Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/a7Mx4/

**SAMPLE HTML**

```
<div id="#left">
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
</div>
```

**Sample CSS**

```
.tile {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ff0000;   
}
```

**jQuery Code**

```
function anim($target){
    $target.animate({'left' : '+=50px'}, 'slow');
}

$('.tile').each(function(index, el){
    var $target = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){anim($target)}, (1000 * index)); // Change 1000 to +/- delay
});
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Why set a timeout when the `.animate()` function provides a callback?

Comment: @Jasper: because you could make animations partially overlapping instead of running sequentially entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Your question interested me so I threw together a quick example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jJ8vJ/

The basic idea is to use the callback function of the jQuery `.animate()` function to iterate through a list of DOM elements to animate.

```
//first I'm setting up the variables I'll need
var $items     = [$('#one'), $('#two'), $('#three'), $('#four')],//stores the DOM elements to be animated in order
    item_index = 0,//stores the current index in the animation queue
    animations = {
        '0px0px'     : { left : '100px', top : '0px' },
        '100px0px'   : { left : '100px', top : '100px' },
        '0px100px'   : { left : '0px'  , top : '0px' },
        '100px100px' : { left : '0px'  , top : '100px' }
    };//this stores the conversion between where the element is and where it should animate to

//setup a function that can call itself inside the animation callback to iterate through the DOM elements to be animated
function run_animation($element) {

    //check to make sure there are more DOM elements to animate, if none are found then the process is done
    if (item_index in $items) {

        //get this element's top and left CSS properties and put them together so we can convert that to the next coordinates it needs
        var css = $items[item_index].css('left') + '' + $items[item_index].css('top');

        //now animate this element by converting the current top/left CSS properties to its next coordinates
        $items[item_index].animate({
            left : animations[css].left,
            top  : animations[css].top
        }, 1500, function () {

            //here we run this same function for the next index
            item_index++;
            run_animation($items[item_index]);
        });
    }
}

//run the animation function for the first time
run_animation($items[item_index]);
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be achieved with the use of the `.each()` method, give all your tiles a class name and do something similar too

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#left").click(function () {
        $('.tiles').each(function() {
            $(this).animate({ "left": "+=50px" }, "slow");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: '$(document).ready(function () {
            var i = 0;
            $("#left").click(function () {
                $('.tile').each(function () {
                    i++;
                    var string = "#s" + i.toString();
                    $(string).animate({ "left": "+=50px" }, "slow");
                });


            });'

Comment: thanx ... i tested this code but that's not work and do the same thing that i had writed! and all the tiles move to the left together!!!

Comment: Yeah.. unfortunately it's a little more involved then just that.  I'll put together a demo but have to leave in a sec so might have to wait a few.  Sorry

Comment: thanx for your time ... i have to solve this problem! ... I use the callback function for 2 elemets but i do'nt know how to use this for variable elements!HOW?!