# Concatenate effects with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, concatenation, chain

I have 4 images (logo-1, logo-2, logo-3 and logo-4) and I want to show them one after the other when I click on a button.

First, I set the height of images to 0 to show them with easeOutBounce effect.

I'm using animate function, but the four images are shown at the same time.

How can I concatenate the animations?

```
<script>
function mostrar(num_logo) {
    if (num_logo <= 4) {
        $("#logo-"+num_logo)    
            .stop().animate(
                {height: '218px'},
                {queue:false, 
                 duration:1000, 
                 easing: 'easeOutBounce',
                 complete: mostrar(num_logo+1)}                             
            );

    }
}
    $(function() {
        // run the currently selected effect
        function runEffect() {

            for (i=1;i<=4;i++) {
                $("#logo-"+i).css('height', '0px');
            }   
            mostrar(1);


        };

        $( "#button" ).click(function() {
            runEffect();
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a jsfiddle I made to answer a very similar question: http://jsfiddle.net/jJ8vJ/ (The question can be found here: [how to animate position in Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189693/how-to-animate-position-in-order/8190007#8190007)).

The basic idea is to set an array of jQuery objects (elements you want to animate in order) and use the callback of the `.animate()` function to animate the elements in order

```
var $items     = [$('#one'), $('#two'), $('#three'), $('#four')],//stores the DOM elements to be animated in order
    item_index = 0,//stores the current index in the animation queue
    animations = {
        '0px0px'     : { left : '100px', top : '0px' },//0px0px means the element is at the top left
        '100px0px'   : { left : '100px', top : '100px' },//100px0px means the element is at the top right
        '0px100px'   : { left : '0px'  , top : '0px' },//0px100px means the element is at the bottom left
        '100px100px' : { left : '0px'  , top : '100px' }//100px100px means the element is at the bottom right
    };//this stores the conversion between where the element is and where it should animate to

//setup a function that can call itself inside the animation callback to iterate through the DOM elements to be animated
function run_animation($element) {

    //check to make sure there are more DOM elements to animate, if none are found then the process is done
    if (item_index in $items) {

        //get this element's top and left CSS properties and put them together so we can convert that to the next coordinates it needs
        var css = $items[item_index].css('left') + '' + $items[item_index].css('top');

        //now animate this element by converting the current top/left CSS properties to its next coordinates
        $items[item_index].animate({
            left : animations[css].left,
            top  : animations[css].top
        }, 1500, function () {

            //here we run this same function for the next index
            item_index++;
            run_animation($items[item_index]);
        });
    }
}

//run the animation function for the first time
run_animation($items[item_index]);
```

Comment: great! Changed the complete to `complete: function () {num_logo++; mostrar(num_logo);}}`

Answer (score 2):

The answer from Jasper is good. I give you some links you should read: they explain some common mistakes you've made in your code and how to avoid them ;)

- [7 Common Javascript Mistakes or Confusions](http://tobyho.com/2011/11/16/7-common-js-mistakes-or-confusions/) (master article)
- [Premature Invocation](http://tobyho.com/2011/10/26/js-premature-invocation/) (your main error)
- [Delaying Repeatedly](http://tobyho.com/2011/11/03/delaying-repeatedly/) (it's what was explained by Jasper, but a bit differently)